# Requirejs almond excluding libs folder?

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, gruntjs, almond

I have a project with a lot of libraries

```
  require.config({
    shim: {
        'fileB' : { deps: ['fileS'] },
        'angular' : { exports: 'angular', deps: ['fileB'] },
        'uiRouter' : { deps: ['angular'] },
        'ngAnimate' : { deps: ['angular'] },
        'lodash' :{ deps:['angular'] },
        'angular-lodash' : { deps:['angular', 'lodash'] }
    },
    paths: {
        'angular' : '../libs/angular.min',
        'ngAnimate' : '../libs/angular-animate.min',
        'uiRouter' : '../libs/angular-ui-router.min',
        'fileS' : 'fileS',
        'lodash' : '../libs/lodash.min',
        'angular-lodash': '../libs/angular-lodash'
    },
    deps: [
        './start'
    ]
});
```

My goal is to put everything in one file except the files in the libs directory

```
    requirejs: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                almond: true,
                replaceRequireScript: [
                    {
                        files: ['dist/index.html'],
                        module: 'config',
                        modulePath: 'config'
                    }
                ],
                name: 'config',
                mainConfigFile: 'tmp/config.js',
                baseUrl: 'tmp',
                out: 'dist/script.min.js'
            }
        }
    },
```

The problem is, when I try to exclude angular it excludes everything. I want to have  the files in the dist directory, everything in the temp should be uglified into one file and libs seperate files. 
Is this possible? Thanks for the help.

Comment: How are you trying to exclude Angular? Have you tried `paths: { "angular": "empty:" }` in the `compile.options`? Also a warning: *I think* that Almond does *NOT* download files; so if you do not include the libraries in the build bundle, you will have to include `<script>`s in your HTML to load stuff. Also, take a look at [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy/).

Comment: You are right, almond does not download it. I changed back to requirejs. Paths is nice to exclude the libs, but then how can I change the pathes to request it from the same folder and no longer from libs ?